# How to convert current year month and day into minutes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i need a variable which is contains the actual year month and day in minutes

that should be around 1061841278

```
var plus = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Current).minute
```

i wrote this but it didn't work...

Comment: Minutes since when? Anyway, take a look at DateInterval or methods in the Date class for calculating a TimeInterval

Comment: `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1061841278)  // "Aug 25, 2003 at 4:54 PM"`

Comment: What date the value `1061841278` represents?

Comment: This feels like you're trying to compute the number of minutes since year 1 or so. Is that correct? You'll need to be very precise about your starting date, and that particular calculation is tricky because it starts before the Gregorian calendar so you need to consider which calendar you mean. The `Calendar` type has the tools you need, but you need to be very precise about what you're asking. It's an unusual reference date; what do you plan to do with this result?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tricky because it looks like your reference date is before the adoption of the Gregorian calendar. So you have to think very hard about what date you're counting from.

But let's assume you mean to count from midnight on January 1 in the year 1 on the Gregorian calendar in UTC. That's kind of a nonsense thing to say, because neither the Gregorian calendar nor UTC existed at that time. But we can extrapolate, and this will show how to approach the problem for other dates.

First, you need a calendar and a timezone to perform the calculations.

```
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let utc = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Then, you need a reference date:

```
let ref = gregorian.date(from: DateComponents(timeZone: utc, year: 1, month: 1, day: 1))!
```

And then you can perform the calculation in minutes:

```
let diff = gregorian.dateComponents([.minute], from: ref, to: Date()).minute
```

When I did this, the answer was 1061841271, which is pretty close to your expectations.

Be very careful with creating reference dates in this era. You will want to read the [Historical Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html) section of the Date and Time Programming Guide to ensure you're dealing with the calendars correctly. In particular, there is no year 0, and `Calendar` skips 10 days in 1582 due to the Julian/Gregorian adjustment.